# Hide directory images from indexing

Tags: android

Can we hide images in Android directory from indexing in Gallery?
I tried create .nomedia programatically there, but it's doesn't work.
Any ideas about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename or create your foldername with dot**(.yourfoldername)** this will hide containing images from indexing in gallery

hope help

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this by using **getExternalFilesDir(null)** instead of **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()**

you can see the developer [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29).

This feature is come from API level-8.